# PHP - PDO - Get Row Count While Using multi-execute

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

==============

```
$query = $this->connection[db::$before_sent['conn']]->prepare(db::$before_sent['sttm']);
        for ($x=0; $x<db::$before_sent['excount']; $x++) {
          $query->execute(db::$before_sent['exval'][$x]);
          db::$after_sent[db::$formname]['rowCount'][] = $query->rowCount();
          $query->nextRowset($x+1);
        }
```

this code , you can see i use rowCount() and nextRowset()
i know that work when i use multiple statement 
but is there are anyway i can do the same with (one statement & Multiple execute) 
as you can see the code [which it return now a wrong rowcount]

thank you !

Comment: why not wrap what you want in a stored proc and have it return the info (out parameter) or in the result set depending on your op

Comment: umm thank you for reply , but actually i know how to get rowcount in another ways , but i'm really want to know if i can use nextRowset() with multiple execute

Comment: rowCount is flakey.